# How do i make my input field width dependent on the button to the right of it?

Tags: html, css, forms, button, width

I have a form on my website. The form consists of one email input field and one "submit" button. The field and the button are on the same line. The button is to the right and the field to the left and there should not be any space between them. I want the button width fixed so that it doesn't become smaller than the text inside it. The email input field however becomes smaller if the browser window is made smaller which is fine.

The issue I have is that when the browser window is made smaller, the button jumps down a line because it the input field pushes it down. I want to somehow set the width of the input field to 100% minus the width of the button. That way they will always stay on the same line.

I've tried this so far:

```
.form {
}

.button_submit {
  float: right;
  width: 78px;
  position: relative;
  height: 33px;
}

.mail_input {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: inser your html

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flexbox` to easily handle things like that instead `float`. I made a solution for you using `flexbox` on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dvsq1ctp/148/

Basicaly the the secret is to set `nowrap` on `flex-flow`, so the element will never wrap.